# Cannot access gii module in yii

Tags: php, yii, gii

I have integrated gii module in my My config file

```
 'modules' => array(
        'gii' => array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
             'password'=>'pick up a password here',
            'generatorPaths' => array(
                'vendor.cornernote.gii-prefixmodel-generator',

            ),
        ),
    ),



    'urlManager'=>array(


        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            'gii'=>'gii',
            'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
            'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',

        ),

    ),
```

I accessed gii by using the following URl.

```
http://local_host/_demo/index.php/gii/
```

I have got an output

```
You are not allowed to access this page.
```

Please help me

Comment: Then also not working

Answer (score 0):

This problem is almost always caused due to ipfilters. A quick way to test is by setting the ipfilters to false. Once it works the correct ip address to update can be found using the command `Yii::app()->request->userHostAddress`. Your gii in `main.php` should look something like this

```
'modules'=>array(
                // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

                'gii'=>array(
                        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
                        'password'=>'admin',
                  // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
                        'ipFilters'=>false,
                ),

        ),
```

Comment: If I add password then also it shows display like same before.

Comment: Did you set the ipfilters?

Comment: Note you must not set the ipfilter as I have shown in the example, this is for test purpose , Ideal way to do this is `'ipFilters' => array('127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.7'),` where 192.168.1.7 is your ip address

Comment: Then also My output like same :(

Comment: can you paste your gii config in main.php along with the ipfilters?

Comment: 'modules' => array(
        'gii' => array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
    'password'=>'admin',
    'ipFilters'=>array('192.168.1.200','192.168.1.200'),
            /*'generatorPaths' => array(
                'vendor.cornernote.gii-prefixmodel-generator',
                //'ext.gii-prefixmodel-generator', // if you downloaded into ext
            ),*/
        ),
    ),

Comment: One way to check if you have configured the correct ip address is to display the output of this command in any view page `Yii::app()->request->userHostAddress` . For testing purpose I would also try to set it to `'ipFilters' => false` and see if that resolves the issue.